# How to prove that the following integral can be reduced to another form with substitution?

Tags: integration

Needs to prove that integral can be reduced to another form with specific substitution. Not sure how it can be proved. I think that t=sin(phi) on second stage but I can't understand how to start.

[image: Pic of task]

Comment: Don't think too much. You are just given a substitution and asked to apply it. Bus assume $\lambda_i<0,$ otherwise the statement is false because the second integrand has real poles whereas the first one does not. And assume $A=1.$ This statement is dubious indeed. Where is it from?